# Polling Outlook mail folder (inbox) occasionally returns ErrorInvalidMailboxItemId

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Something strange occurs that I cannot find the cause or reason for.

I have a loop which polls Inbox for an authorized user every minute. This goes fine for some time, but then I get 404 and error code is ErrorInvalidMailboxItemId (Item Id doesn't belong to the current mailbox.). I for example get this two times and then the polls starts working again.

GET /v1.0/me/mailFolders/xxx/messages?$filter=isRead%20ne%20true&$count=true&$top=10

Nothing that I can see is different between the polls, so I'm baffled why server suddenly returns 404.
Searching for this error mentions shared mailbox, archive and delegated, however this inbox is neither of these, and besides the error should then be consistent which it is not.

Same bearer token used for all the polls, both when it works, then does not and then when it starts working again.

Any ideas why this goes wrong? Or do I have to look for this error and then just retry or ignore the error for some time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

1. Do a re-try and see if it works
2. Implement the detailed response logging at the custom application end, isolate the item, make the same API call in MS Graph Explorer and see if it exists, gets the data or not.
3. Make sure you have necessary permissions to access the shared mailbox, archive mailboxes or the targeted mailboxes etc